# Can you target an elements parent element using event.target?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the innerHTML of my page to become the innerHTML of the element I click on. The only problem is that I want it to take the whole element such as:

```
    <section 
      class="homeItem"> 
      <div>
        <!-- more HTML here -->
      </div>
    </section>
```

Whereas the code that I have written in Javascript:

```
function selectedProduct(event){
  target = event.target;
  element = document.getElementById("test");
  element.innerHTML = target.innerHTML;
}
```

will target the specific element that I click on.

What I would like to achieve is when I click on anywhere in the `<section>` element, that it will take the innerHTML of the whole `<section>` element, rather than the specific one that I have clicked.

I would presume it is something to do with selecting the parent element of the one that is clicked, but I am not sure and can't find anything online.

If possible, I would like to stay away from JQuery.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

I think what you need is to use the `event.currentTarget`. This will contain the element that actually has the event listener. So if the whole `<section>` has the eventlistener `event.target` will be the clicked element, the `<section>` will be in `event.currentTarget`.

Otherwise `parentNode` might be what you're looking for.

[link to currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)
[link to parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)

Comment: saved me day!, event.target is the smallest tag at mouse, event.currentTarget is the one with event triggered

Comment: Seems counter-intuitive.  I would think `currentTarget` should represent the element clicked, while `target` should be what the event was set on.

Comment: that was exactly what i looked for, thank you first, but i have one question, when i log the event object in my function, the currentTarget is null but still i am able to get the id from my dataset attribute, is the logged event still is the same e.target?

Answer (score 84):

To use the parent of an element use `parentElement`:

```
function selectedProduct(event){
  var target = event.target;
  var parent = target.parentElement;//parent of "target"
}
```

Comment: While this answers OP's question, I think OP's problem should be solved with `currentTarget`.

Comment: This gave me the top level parent element which is not what i was looking for, thank you anyway i will keep this in mind for my future coding

Answer (score 24):

```
handleEvent(e) {
  const parent = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

```
function getParent(event)
{
   return event.target.parentNode;
}
```

> **Examples:**
>   1. `document.body.addEventListener("click", getParent, false);` returns the parent element of the current element that you have clicked.
>
> 2. If you want to use inside any function then pass your event and call the function like this :
>      
>      `function yourFunction(event){
>          var parentElement = getParent(event);
>      }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `closest()` to get your desired ancestor/parent:

```
const target = event.target;
const parent = target.closest('section');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var _RemoveBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("remove");
for(var i=0 ;  i<_RemoveBtn.length ; i++){
    _RemoveBtn[i].addEventListener('click',sample,false);
}
function sample(event){
    console.log(event.currentTarget.parentNode);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", function(event){
   var a = $(event.target).parents();
   var flaghide = true;
    a.each(function(index, val){
       if(val == $(container)[0]){
           flaghide = false;
        }
    });
    if(flaghide == true){
        //required code
    }
})
```

Comment: `"If possible, I would like to stay away from JQuery."`

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I did it by targeting `event.target.parentNode`. You can also chain that to go higher up your DOM tree, ie `event.target.parentNode.parentNode`.