# Javascript get "clicked" element addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I know I can grab the element of an individual ID.

Anyway I can attach a listener to the parent div and pass the ID of the individual span that was clicked?

```
<div id = "divId">
  <span id="one"></span>
  <span id="two"> </span>
 </div>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", someFunction);
```

Comment: Can you make this a little clearer? Sounds like you want to read up on event bubbling but not totally sure.

Comment: What? You want the clicked element? Use [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) to get a reference to an actual element which was clicked.

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event

Comment: If none of the answers work or you wanted something else, let me know so I can help

Comment: Yeah i cant seem to get the span id when I click on the span

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the `event` object and access its `target` property

```js
document.getElementById("divId").addEventListener("click", someFunction);

function someFunction(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="divId">
  <span id="one">one</span>
  <span id="two"> two</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Teemu, `event` is a default object bound to handlers in js

Comment: @Teemu, I may be wrong, but I thought `event` was like `arguments` where you can access it without passing it in

Comment: It is not. In older IEs it was a global object though.

Comment: @Teemu, out of curiosity, how was it working before when I did not pass it in?

Comment: It wasn't, I saw "ReferenceError: event is not defined"  on my console. Now it works. - Sorry I forgot, Chrome has implemented the global `event` too, but it's not a part of any standard. I'm on FF, which gave the error

Comment: @Teemu, oh ok. It was working for me on chrome. So this definately seems like an unstable usage for cross-browsers... thanks again for the useful tip

Comment: if i do an alert...it will only give me the ID of the div.  If I click on the spans the alert pops up and its empty???

Comment: @DocHoliday, interesting. Are you using the code from my most recent answer? what browser? can you replicate it in a fiddle?

Comment: @DocHoliday, ok, figured it out. For the cases of an empty alert, it was alerting an inner span which was clicked that had no id. For other cases of alerting 'divId' this is because the span real estate did not cover that area. To know span real estate, inspect the element and look at its highlihgt. Always remember the inner most span clicked will be the event.target. See it alerting the sub spans here  http://jsfiddle.net/8t9cqyqd/1/

Comment: @AmmarCSEI was just about to come post that I had the ID's on the wrong spans!!  Thanks for helping me with this!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

If the user clicked on a node that was a child of the element the user wanted to test `e.target` will be a different node. The sensible way to check this nowadays is to listen at the document level and iterate the path (or use some delegation library, of which there are many):

Add one event listener to the document:

```
const isOnId = (path,id) => path.some(element => element.id === id);

document.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  if(isOnId(e.path,'two')) {
    //you clicked on or in element with an id two
  } else {
    //you clicked on something else
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Adam's answer is correct and saves a lot of headaches. However there's a better and easiest way to acieve this. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29168819/5213598)

Makes use of Event.currentTarget and it goes like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="list_item" data-mydata="hello there!">
    <img src="..." alt="" width="50", height="50">
  </li>
  <li class="list_item" data-mydata="hello world">
    <img src="..." alt="" width="50", height="50">
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
  const items = document.querySelectorAll(".list_item");
  items.forEach(node => {
    node.addEventListener("click", e => {
      let myvalue = e.currentTarget.dataset.mydata;
      console.log(myvalue); //hello there! || hello world It depends on which element the user has clicked
    })
  })
</script>
```

I hope this is useful

Answer (score 2):

*Since I do not have enough credits to comment, adding a new answer.*

Unlike the answer shared by @CubeInTheBox, I think leveraging the concept of event capturing/bubbling for the respective element makes for a better implementation rather than adding an event listener to each of the target elements.
For the example shared above, the alternative would be:

```
 <ul>
     <li class="list_item" data-mydata="hello there!">
         <img src="..." alt="" width="50", height="50">
     </li>
     <li class="list_item" data-mydata="hello world">
        <img src="..." alt="" width="50", height="50">
     </li>
 </ul>
 
 <script>
     const parentElement = document.querySelector('ul');
     parentElement.addEventListener('click', e => {
         // If you want to add the listener on li alone and not on image
         if (e.target.className === 'list_item') {
             const myvalue = e.target.dataset.mydata;
             console.log(myvalue);
         }
     });
 </script>
```

NOTE that `e.currentTarget` wouldn’t work for this case, as it would return the parent `ul` to which the event is bound.