# How do I use querySelectorAll on my class names

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make my site responsive to handheld actions. I have four images, all with the class="grid-photos". I am trying to make the photos expand when clicked, and close when clicked again.

```
        <div class="grid-container">
         <img class="grid-photos">
         <img class="grid-photos">
         <img class="grid-photos">
         <img class="grid-photos">
```

As of now I can get it to work only with the first image using this Javascript

```
const gridPhotos = document.querySelector(".grid-photos");

document.querySelectorAll(".grid-photos").forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    gridPhotos.classList.toggle("expander");
  });
});
```

I have tried querySelectorAll with [i] but to no avail.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Just use `item` or `event.target` instead of `gridPhotos` before `classList`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript get "clicked" element addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786154/javascript-get-clicked-element-addeventlistener)

Comment: Use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple events — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your variable `gridPhotos` is a collection of all your grid photos. So when you call `.classList` on it you'll get an error about it being undefined.

What you need to to is get the correct element from the event instead. `event.target` will return the element that was clicked so you can use that to add a class to the correct image.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".grid-photos").forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.target.classList.toggle("expander");
  });
});
```

```css
.expander {
  border: 4px solid green; /* Added to highlight which one was clicked */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <img class="grid-photos" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-l7M0ldZDNZs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rf7tyiXmVY3yNjeGjVZCZdKL2qObw/photo.jpg?sz=32">
  <img class="grid-photos" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-l7M0ldZDNZs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rf7tyiXmVY3yNjeGjVZCZdKL2qObw/photo.jpg?sz=32">
  <img class="grid-photos" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-l7M0ldZDNZs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rf7tyiXmVY3yNjeGjVZCZdKL2qObw/photo.jpg?sz=32">
  <img class="grid-photos" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-l7M0ldZDNZs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rf7tyiXmVY3yNjeGjVZCZdKL2qObw/photo.jpg?sz=32">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrong selector `querySelector` select just 1, `querySelectorAll` select all items example:

```js
const gridPhotos = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-photos");

gridPhotos.forEach(function (item) {
  item.onclick = function()
  {
    this.classList.toggle("expander");
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <img class="grid-photos" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img class="grid-photos" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img class="grid-photos" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
```