# When clicking on one of the tags with the same class as javascript, how to access the clicked one?

Tags: javascript, html, class, onclick, click

When clicking on one of the tags with the same class as javascript, how to access the clicked one? I tried by clicking, I looked at the problems, but unfortunately I could not solve the problem, it is very important for me, thanks in advance. Kind regards

**HTML:**

```
<div class="money-select">
                                <div class="money-check">
                                    <div class="money-check-left">
                                        <img src="https://cdn.dsmcdn.com/ty100/product/media/images/20210408/17/78753423/161972772/0/0_org_zoom.jpg">
                                        <h2>BTC</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="money-check-right">
                                        <i class="fi-xwsdxl-chevron-wide"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <div class="money-check">
                                        <div class="money-check-left">
                                            <img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/ethereum-2296075-1912034.png">
                                            <h2>ETH</h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>  
                                    <div class="money-check">
                                        <div class="money-check-left">
                                            <img src="https://cryptologos.cc/logos/thumbs/bnb.png?v=022">
                                            <h2>BNB</h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="money-check">
                                        <div class="money-check-left">
                                            <img src="https://cryptologos.cc/logos/thumbs/shiba-inu.png?v=022">
                                            <h2>SHIBA</h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>  
                                    <div class="money-check">
                                        <div class="money-check-left">
                                            <img src="https://cryptologos.cc/logos/thumbs/decentraland.png?v=022">
                                            <h2>DTC</h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

**JS:**

```
let moneySelect = document.querySelector(".money-select");
let moneyList = moneySelect.querySelector(".money-check");
let moneyValue = moneyList.querySelector("h1");
let input = document.getElementById("htmlinamk");

for (var i = 0; i < moneyList.length; i++) {
    moneyList[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        a = moneyValue.innerText;
        input.value = a;
    });
}
```

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript get "clicked" element addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786154/javascript-get-clicked-element-addeventlistener)

Comment: Also your friend's problem is jquery, my problem is with normal JavaScript

Comment: Please look again I edited the comment to point to a different answer.

Comment: I'm new to javascript. I want to get the ,H2 inside the class Div selected in the dropdown. But all Div's classes are the same. That's why I'm getting the undefined error. :( I would like to state that I did not understand anything in the link you sent.

Answer (score 0):

The event listener function receives the `event` object, which has a `target` property that would point to the div element with class `money-check`. You could then traverse the DOM tree and get down to child of child and extract the inner text from the header tag. Something like this:

```js
moneyList[i].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
 const innerText = event.target.child<traverse here>.innerText;
 input.value = innerText;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to get the element that was clicked.  `this`, or `event.target`.  Either of the techniques will work for this example:

```
moneyList[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    let a = this.querySelector('H2').innerText;
    // let a = e.target.querySelector('H2').innerText;
    input.value = a;
});
```