# How can I remove the clicked "li" Element with eventlistener?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list looking like this. Can I somehow remove just 1 of the li elements with eventlistener and without changing the HTML? I can remove them all by this JS code here under, but I want to remove them in the order I click.

```js
document.querySelector("ol").addEventListener('click', whenClick);

// function to remove rows

function whenClick(event) {
  const li = document.querySelector('.item');
  li.remove();
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="item">Första</li>
  <li class="item">Andra</li>
  <li class="item">Tredje</li>
  <li class="item" id="fifth">Femte</li>
  <li class="item">Sjätte</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: use `e.currentTarget`

Comment: I re-opened since this is not tagged jQuery

Comment: @mplungjan - Why? Again, the answers are the same, and now neither of us can add a previous version of the question (you **know** there are dozens) with DOM only. Such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786154/javascript-get-clicked-element-addeventlistener).

Comment: @mplungjan - I guess I misremembered that you can't dupehammer after reopening.

Comment: I can still close with the slightly better dupe. My answer seems to be more suited that any of the dupes I could find. Most of them are ancient, uses jQuery or have inline event handlers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just remove the target

I check if it is an LI

```js
document.querySelector("ol").addEventListener('click', whenClick);

// function to remove rows

function whenClick(event) {
  const tgt = event.target;
  if (!tgt.matches("li")) return
  tgt.remove();
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="item">Första</li>
  <li class="item">Andra</li>
  <li class="item">Tredje</li>
  <li class="item" id="fifth">Femte</li>
  <li class="item">Sjätte</li>
</ol>
```

If you have elements inside the LI we can do this

```js
document.querySelector("ol").addEventListener('click', whenClick);

// function to remove rows

function whenClick(event) {
  const tgt = event.target.closest("li");
  if (tgt) tgt.remove();
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="item"><span>Första</span></li>
  <li class="item">Andra</li>
  <li class="item">Tredje</li>
  <li class="item" id="fifth">Femte</li>
  <li class="item">Sjätte</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: ***Massive*** dupe, as you like to say.

Comment: @LukasE Varsågod - pls reload to see an extra version

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I would normally agree, but the dupes [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+remove+li+element+on+click+site:stackoverflow.com) are not great, use jQuery or inline event handlers

Comment: @mplungjan Tack så mycket :D Are you Swedish? :)

Comment: Nej, jeg er dansk :)

Comment: Voted down because it's a "massive dupe"? I seriously tried to find something that was the exact same and failed